# jquery datepicker max date min date control using two date picker

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

what I have : I have two datepicker calender control in jquery where 1st can only choose date current date and previous date but not future date for that I have written the code which works fine

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
   $("#from").datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });

   });
  </script>
```

Now I have to use another textbox with datepicker which can only select dates between the date selected in 1st textbox and current date.

Now having these conditions what code should I write for my second datepicker.

my project is in Asp .net using c#. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $("#from").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (date) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
                $("#to").datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date());
            },
            maxDate: 0
        });

    }); 
    </script>
```